# Deployment issue- Need for Cusotm Setup file-VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, installation

I have 4 different outlook addins and I want to make it in a single setup file by giving the user the option to select whatever addin they need during the installation.

How can I do this in Visual Studio Tools 2010.

As of now, I have created  a setup file, which will install all the 4 addins at one single go.

Any kind of links to these kind of setup, or tips are needed in moving forward this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't support this. You need a setup authoring tool which allows you to use custom features and organize your resources using those features. A dialog editor would also help.

Here is the general approach:

- create 4 features, one for each addin
- move each addin resources into it's feature
- use setup type dialog (Typical, Custom and Complete options) to allow the user to select the features he wants
- if the setup authoring tool you are using has a dialog editor, you can use a custom dialog instead of setup type dialog (for example a button for each addin instead of a feature tree)

If you want a free solution, you can try [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It has a steep learning curve, but you can do what you want with it. A commercial solution is easier to use, but you have to purchase a license. Let me know if you want some recommendations.

Comment: Can you point me to some Wix Tutorials to get started with building a custom installation for Visual Studio 2010